# Is it impossible to find the "exact" value (like 3,1415926) of a non exact square root without knowing the nearest exact square root?

Tags: roots, radicals

> Is it impossible to find the "exact" value (like 3,1415926) of a non exact square root without knowing the nearest exact square root?

I looked in a lot of sites and youtube videos, and i can't find any equation for it.

Comment: Is it certainly impossible to find a non-exact square root without **doing any calculations at all**, and if you are doing some calculations, you might just as well find the nearest exact square root.

Answer (score 1):

When we approximate a non-exact square root we start with the greatest integer less than the square root and start adding decimal digits to have a better and better approximation. For example for $\sqrt 5$ we start with $2$ and go to $$\{2,2.2,2.23,2.236, 2.2360,....\}$$

Similarly with $\sqrt{27}$ we start with $5$ and go through $$\{5, 5.1,5.19, 5.196,...\}$$

Comment: But let say i need to know the square root of 7.039.725, how should i figure out what is the greatest exact square root below it? It doesn't exists any equation for solving this problem?

Comment: @Toniotti you want some function that gives $F(7.039725) = 4$ ?

Comment: Yes. I'am trying to use log, but i don't know if that's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably a ridiculous answer.*

You are looking for the square root of a number $a$ and you have no idea about *the greatest exact square root below (or above) it*. In any manner, it means that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^2-a$$
Assuming $a >1$, we see that $f(a)=a^2-a >0$ and the second derivative is positive. Then, by Darboux theorem, starting Newton method with $x_0=a$ will converge to the solution without any overshoot of the solution. As usual, the iterates will be given by
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n) }{f'(x_n) }=\frac{x_n^2+a}{2 x_n}$$

Using your example $a=7039725$, this would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 7039725.000 \\
 1 & 3519863.000 \\
 2 & 1759932.500 \\
 3 & 879968.2500 \\
 4 & 439988.1250 \\
 5 & 220002.0624 \\
 6 & 110017.0304 \\
 7 & 55040.50901 \\
 8 & 27584.20490 \\
 9 & 13919.70673 \\
 10 & 7212.722377 \\
 11 & 4094.368672 \\
 12 & 2906.868156 \\
 13 & 2664.312010 \\
 14 & 2653.270982 \\
 15 & 2653.248010 
\end{array}
\right)$$